# need to use ROW_NUMBER without over in sqlserver 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ROW_NUMBER() without over in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12914499/row-number-without-over-in-sql)

I have a grid with sorting on each column and have to show only 50 rows at a time.

I am using sql server 2005 as database.

Now there is ROW_NUMBER function in sql server 2005 to filter the data with row number but `Over(order by [Column])` is mandatory to use. In my case I have to sort my grid with different columns so I can not use the static columns name in order by clause. The restriction is , I have to use static query.

Can you guys help me out on this problem?

Comment: [You might find my answer here useful but expect bad performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623167/removing-duplication-in-dynamic-row-number-over-order-by-statement/12623397#12623397)

Comment: @MartinSmith . did you get my question. Can I use Row_number without over or with dynamic order by column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use several ROW_NUMBER clauses per column and choose the relevant one:

```
....
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Column1]) as rn1,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Column2]) as rn2,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Column3]) as rn3,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Column4]) as rn4
....
```

**OR** use a CASE expression. Note: all datatypes must be compatible

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CASE @sort
                     WHEN 1 THEN [Column1]
                     WHEN 1 THEN [Column2]
                     WHEN 1 THEN [Column3]
                     ...
                   END
```

**OR** If you really want an arbitrary row number then do this:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) as rn
```

Answer (score 0):

I found some way to do it.

```
SELECT
  OrderID, CustomerID, EmployeeID, OrderDate, ShippedDate,
  @Offset, @Limit, @SortColumn, @SortDirection
FROM
  Orders
WHERE
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
  (
    ORDER BY
      /* same expression as in the ORDER BY of the whole query */
  ) BETWEEN (@PageNum - 1) * @PageSize + 1 AND @PageNum * @PageSize 
  /* AND more conditions ... */
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN @SortDirection = 'A' THEN
    CASE @SortColumn 
      WHEN 'OrderID'    THEN OrderID
      WHEN 'CustomerID' THEN CustomerID
      /* more... */
    END
  END,
  CASE WHEN @SortDirection = 'D' THEN
    CASE @SortColumn 
      WHEN 'OrderID'    THEN OrderID
      WHEN 'CustomerID' THEN CustomerID
      /* more... */
    END 
  END DESC
```